# MS-CRM 2013 Invalid party object type 9

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to send a notification email after creating a contact in CRM.

For that I have written the following code.. but it is throwing an exception of "Invalid Party object type 9". I searched for it but could't find reasonable help

Thanks

**code :**

```csh
  //Defining Activity Parties (starts)
  Entity Fromparty = new Entity("activityparty");
  Entity Toparty = new Entity("activityparty");

  //set partyid
  Toparty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("contact", ContactGuid.Id);
  Fromparty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("team", ConsumerTeam.Id);

  //create email entity
  Entity Email = new Entity("email");
  Email["from"] = new Entity[] { Fromparty };
  Email["to"] = new Entity[] { Toparty };
  Email["subject"] = "Account Login Information";
  Email["description"] = PopulateBody(UserName,Password);
  Email["directioncode"] = true;
  Email["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("contact", ContactGuid.Id);
  Guid EmailID = Service.Create(Email);

  //Sending email
  SendEmailRequest reqSendEmail = new SendEmailRequest();
  reqSendEmail.EmailId = EmailID;//ID of created mail
  reqSendEmail.TrackingToken = "";
  reqSendEmail.IssueSend = true;
  SendEmailResponse res = (SendEmailResponse)Common.Common.Execute(reqSendEmail);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to set the `from` attribute of an `Email` entity to a `Team`.
This is not possible because the `from` attribute can be only a `user` or a `queue`:

[image]

You get `Invalid Party object type 9` because 9 is the entitycode for `team` entity.

Change your code in order to set the `from` to be a user or a queue record.

Comment: Guido : thanks it worked........... i would definitely suggest this answer but unfortunately don't have points :p

Comment: i would definitely marked it as answered ... but unable now because of less reputations in stackoverflow